# How to append characters to each element in a list

Tags: r

I have a column of strings that I want to append each of them with _at. Is there an easier way to do this in excel?

I have

```
D1
543
734
```

I want

```
D1
543_at
734_at
```

Comment: Is this an *R* or an *Excel* question?

Comment: I suspect its a case of "would it be easier to do this in Excel rather than R?" to which the answer is always "no".

Answer (score 4):

If it's an R question, `paste0` on a data frame like this:

```
> d=data.frame(a=c("foo","bar","baz"),b=c(3,6,5))
> d
    a b
1 foo 3
2 bar 6
3 baz 5
> d$a=paste0(d$a,"_at")
> d
       a b
1 foo_at 3
2 bar_at 6
3 baz_at 5
```

If it's an Excel question, change the tags.